# How to overcome the problem Session Timeout in Android Webview

Tags: android

I have created one android application using android webview. The website which i have loaded is have some session timeout (40 minutes. after 40minutes we have to relogin) . anyone please tell me how do i can keep the user always login without any session timout restriction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The duration and length of the session are controlled by the server. Unless the server grants you a longer lasting session you won't be able to do that.

Otherwise you'd have to store the user credentials and reauthenticate periodically. I wouldn't recommend that for security and logistical reasons though.

I would ask your server developers to give you longer lasting sessions if you need them. They probably chose the session length for a reason though.

Comment: thank you so much  for your reply.. this helped me